# “Why does a Moon-rock taste better than an Earth-rock?” joke meaning

Tags: meaning, puns, jokes

In the last episode of “The Last of Us” TV show there is the following pun:

> Why does a Moon-rock taste better than an Earth-rock?
> Because it's a little meteor.

What's the wordplay here?

P.S. I've found it in an old “Futurama” episode also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because "meteor" sounds like "meatier" when you say it?